# Proper grounding and service wire choice for remote load center, RV pedestal

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm setting up a trailer pad at home and will be running service to a load center for the trailer and additional power to back yard area (about 100').  My only question to resolve is the proper way to set up the ground at the load center pedestal.  I'll be setting up a 50 amp 240v service using this panel [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00A8FQUYW/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A8FQUYW)

If I read [the comments below by these experienced electricians correctly](https://www.mikeholt.com//forum/Forum1/HTML/004432.html)  then

*I should bury an [additional ground conductor (ECG) i.e. a 4-4-4-4](https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/4-4-4-4-tulsa-underground-secondary-distribution-cable.html) and not bond the neutral to ground at the load center but connect ground of load center back to the main service panel with the additional conductor.*

*I wonder if in additional to that it would be prudent to set a ground rod at the pedestal and tie that to the same unbonded ground of the load center as well.  Or is that overkill or simply ill advised?*

**If you have some experience with this issue would appreciate your thoughts.**

> Jim, Take a look at 551.76. RV Pedestals SHALL BE GROUNDED by a
>   continuous EGC run with the feeder conductors for the pedestal row.
>   551.76 (C), The neutral SHALL NOT be used as an EGC. Having said all of this, ground rods at each pedestal would not be required, however
>   after much investigation, in California for some reason, the AHJ wants
>   ground rods at each pedestal and NO EGC run with the feeders. No
>   matter which method is used, the neutral is not grounded or bonded at
>   the pedestals.
>
> Name: Wayne Foster Email: hurk27@attbi.com Location: Indiana Title:
>   Electrician In Trade Since: 1976 Registered: Jan 2002 Total Posts: 768
>     posted November 15, 2002 at 01:12 AM       Edit/Delete Message "the
>   AHJ wants ground rods at each pedestal and NO EGC run with the
>   feeders. No matter which method is used, the neutral is not grounded
>   or bonded at the pedestals."
>
> Talk about a dangerous setup if a appliance were to go to ground the
>   earth would not provide a low enough impedance path to trip a 5 amp
>   breaker!!! and the whole RV would be hot to earth!! could you imagine
>   what would happen if a elderly couple touch the door and fell dead.
>   guess whoo they would go after? the installer not the local AHJ.
>
> 80.29 Liability for Damages. Article 80 shall not be construed to affect the responsibility or liability of any party owning, designing,
>   operating, controlling, or installing any electric equipment for
>   damages to persons or property caused by a defect therein, nor shall
>   the _____ or any of its employees be held as assuming any such
>   liability by reason of the inspection, reinspection, or other
>   examination authorized. ```

Comment: Aluminum is good, but that AA-1350 alloy in that cable is outlawed for your use. You should use AA - 8000 alloys. Also, on that panel, I would advise more spaces. You'll thank me later.

Comment: Guess you are right about that alloy https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/2016/01/18/aluminum-alloy-conductors-45-years-of-reliable-installations/ .  If it can't be used by code why does anyone sell it.  I can't find any URD direct bury prices with that alloy.  The SER cable is 8000 at 4x the price! and must go in a conduit.    Alternatively might go with UF/B copper if I can get away with #6 at only 2.5x.  Sigh...just add more money.  Hope it's 4x more safe.

Comment: @DKebler -- why are you stuffing cables down conduits to begin with?  If you're tossing a conduit in the ground, it's no more expensive (and quite a bit easier) to pull individual wires through it instead!

Comment: @DKebler -- the deal is that AA-1350 URD/USE is still technically legal, just not a good idea to use for much of anything.

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-By-the-Foot-2-2-2-4-Black-Stranded-AL-Quad-Dyke-URD-Cable-55417399/205001803  Even home depot sells the 1350 URD.  Southwire even makes it and sells it.   Something is kinda stinky.  Can't find a price for URD AA-8000 wire anywhere online, everyone is selling 1350.  If I use this 1350 is my trailer which has two 10 amp circuit breakers going to melt this cable (not).  Is the electrical police going to come and tell me I can't use this wire.  Although the load center is rated for 125 was only going to use a 50amp double pole breaker at the main panel.

Comment: Just did a live chat with pratt.com.  They don't even sell 8000 URD.   So it seems that if 8000 alloy is required you MUST buy the SER at 4x and put in a conduit.  Someone enlighten me.

Comment: Power companies follow different rules for power *distribution* because evetything is outdoors where it can't set a building on fire and can't be touched inadvertently. The  demarcation point is outside your house, so service latetals and drops are in power company territory. URD is only rated for service laterals not feeder, and the four wire is for three phase. Home Depot shouldn't sell it, but they sell lots of things they shouldn't because people buy them. They also charge prices they shouldn't. Best advice, stop buying there.

Comment: @DKebler -- if you're running wire in conduit, USE SINGLE WIRES (XHHW-2 AA-8000), *not a cable!*  You'll thank me for this advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "electrician in trade since 1976". In 1976 a 3-wire groundless connection was legal. Certainly not today.

Even a 1976, a separate neutral and ground wire was an improvement. He made it sound like the AHJ would prohibit it, seems unlikely.

Today, belt and suspenders is mandatory. All sub panels must have ground and neutral brought separately, with separation in the sub panel. And then, an outbuilding or other off site location needs a separate ground rod.

And unless the ground rod tests to 25 ohms, it needs two ground rods. Unless you have the equipment, testing is more expensive than driving a second ground rod.

### If you're in conduit, use THWN or XHHW. It's cheaper.

if the conduit run is continuous, don't choke cable down it, use individual THWN or XHHW conductors. Your neutral can be smaller and your ground can be much smaller.

For instance I just priced 2/2/4/6 in XHHW and it was $120 for 100 feet.   I don't see any 2/2/2/4 URD or anything out there at that price.

Mind you I got these prices **by calling my local electrical supply house**: trying to buy wiring on the Internet doesn't really work. Too many prices are sucker prices, or lowball but "gee, we're out of stock but thanks for joining my email list" prices, and then there's shipping to contend with. There is also junk imported from far-east places that use US wire sizes.  You don't want that. US big-box stores don't have any selection.  Proper electrical supply houses aren't online, these things have a very low price-to-weight ratio, so selling online is a fool's game.

### Why URD is not a good fit for feeder

*Feeder, service lateral and distribution are three separate and different things.  Your location is on your side of the meter, which makes yours feeder*.

Power companies follow a completely different and more liberal code.  They are allowed to use AA-1350 aluminum, it was designed for power transmission and distribution after all!  URD is intended for distribution (pole to pole) or service lateral (pole to demarcation point which is before the meter) and that is abundantly clear:

- from product descriptions (which say that plainly, even if many don't understand the terms and so, disregard them)
- [product brochures](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/4a/4a691843-2a1c-4e6d-8e60-8a327d4dfb0e.pdf) (note the truly screwball ampacity ratings, and *footnote* that "by the way" these don't apply to NEC usage which must come from NEC's tables).  This is glossed over because product users are expected to know it.

Now if you selected this cable because of these wild ampacity ratings like 120A for #4, that doesn't work at all. You need to use NEC rules for determining ampacity. For instance #4 Al has the same ampacity as #6 Cu, only good for a 60A subpanel.

So why does groundless 2/2/2/4 URD exist? For service laterals for three-phase wye service, hot-hot-hot-neutral, either wye or wild-leg delta. Why does Home Depot sell it? Because it sells.  Given how bad their help is, I'm sure a lot of what they sell is misapplied, or wasted when the inspector catches it.

Also, the cable does not have a ground wire.  People look at the yellow striped smaller wire and go "that's the ground because yellow is kinda like green". No, it's the neutral.  It's legal to remark #4 or larger wires, so it would need to be marked with green tape to make it a ground, and a hot conductor would need to be re-marked with white tape to be neutral.   I bet almost nobody does that.

A fair bit of googling reveals many claims that URD is not legal inside any home.  The claims are that NEC doesn't mention URD so it's not a proper wiring method.  That does make sense.

Comment: You *could* use 2-2-2-4 URD/USE-2 for an underground (direct bury) feeder (H-H-N-G) but I wouldn't either due to AA-1350 being a known issue for terminations.

Comment: Lots of folks using this for exact same as I intend.  https://www.amazon.com/Aluminum-2-2-2-4-Direct-Quadruplex-Secondary/dp/B00A4I6VZG#customerReviews.  You and @Harper say don't do it, ok, but can you point me to an aa-8000 alternative and supplier and some idea of price cause when I search I find nothing except wholesalers.   Also if termination is a problem is there any way to at least mitigate the issue if $$ force me to use this.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel what about the fact that there 's no identified ground wire? Are you allowed to remark neutral as ground and use one of the phases for neutral?

Comment: @Harper -- I'd say so, yeah, given the gauge of the conductors involved

Comment: Although one point -- I *have* noticed a mixed bag of electrical supply houses and things that can stand in for them on many items (typically industrial MRO houses, although automation-type suppliers also carry some of the things an electricial supply house will) popping up online, although some of them play the "call for quote" game all the same...

Comment: Latest edits and comments are very helpful.  This post started with a grounding question but really turned into a proper wire choice question which is important so I'm editing the title

Comment: Found 2/2/4/6 8000 online for $1.04/ft https://www.nassaunationalcable.com/2-2-4-6-feeder.html with shipping about $180.  1.25" conduit should work at about at $1.50 per ft. so another $150 so over $330 to be kosher vs URD https://www.nassaunationalcable.com/2-qaudruplex.html about the same price.  You save the cost of $150 of conduit to be "not code" for 100' run.

Comment: If like me you leave 3 hours from a city of any size then online may be only option.  So another vendor good for west coast with 4.8 google rating and only $33.50 shipping https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/2-2-4-6-aluminum-mobile-home-feeder-cable.html

Comment: and finally a better price on 1.25" PVC conduit at of course HD.  only about $.52 per ft.  https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-1-4-in-x-10-ft-PVC-Schedule-40-Conduit-67470/100196693.  Should fit based on this table.  http://www.elliottelectric.com/StaticPages/ElectricalReferences/ElectricalTables/Conduit_Fill_Table_PVC.aspx.  Thx all.  I'll do it the right way, NEC code :-).

Comment: There ya go. Side by side you present the wrong cable and the right cable, and from the same vendor, they are about the same price.  That's what I expected because on large cable, the ruling factor is actually the metal mineral value.  Note MH feeder's correct striping, and is also legal for direct burial, so no need for conduit. The $76 to ship 30 lbs of cable is pure profiteering. Is there a specific reason not to use XHHW/THWN or are you just missing what we're saying because you don't understand it?  It is actually made to be pulled, unlike cable.

Comment: @DKebler on the "not near city of any size" I am skeptical. **Local electricians have to buy it somewhere, they don't each stock it**. My favorite electrical supply is in Harrisonburg VA, tucked back in the Shenandoah 3 hours from DC or Norfolk.  I am confident I could get common wires at sane prices in Elkins WV, Evanston WY, Houghton MI, or Clearlake CA. The rural ones can be the friendliest, Womack sure is.  Ask at your local family lumberyard or lighting supply house who the nearby electrical supplies are.

Comment: DIdn't read carefully.  Looks like that USE-2 mobile home feeder is ok direct bury and it's 8000 alloy.  https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/2-2-4-6-aluminum-mobile-home-feeder-cable.html   Different story out in rural eastern OR it's 90 miles+ to any electric supply, 3 hours to Boise.  Local hardware said don't order wire from them too expensive.

Comment: @DKebler -- one note -- you have the wrong conduit, and probably want bigger anyway -- 2" Schedule 80 is what I'd use here, although 1.5" Schedule 80 is acceptable.  You don't want Schedule 40 as it's not thick-walled enough to handle physical damage, which matters especially at the stub-ups

Comment: After some further investigation I am thinking it's better not to have a reduced size neutral so will be going with 2-2-2-4 and not 2-2-4-6.  https://www.quora.com/Why-is-a-neutral-wire-thinner-than-a-phase-wire

Comment: Yeah you were price conscious which is why I did that.  Mind you my recommendation was for individual conductors, which makes it easy to change your mind without scouring the web for a peculiar multiconductor cable that has exactly the right combination.  So you order 300' of #2 instead of 200' of #2 and 100' of #1, cost diff about $9. The individual conductors *would* fit in a 1-1/4 conduit, but I'd still heed TPE's advice unless you have an electrician's truck full of pulling tools.